# subversion problem - commit access

Tags: svn

I'm new to setting up subversion but originally when I made a repository, all my team members could update and commit without problem. There was a problem with it so we decided to recreate it, but now only I can commit changes to it. And my username/password doesn't work on their computers, so I'm sure it's something obvious and silly, but I just don't know enough to know what's causing it.

The passwd and svnserve.conf files are the same as the original repository that worked for everyone.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move to server fault? - not a programming question

Comment: Does everyone have access to the machine on which the repository exists?  Do they have svn access (are they in the svn group in /etc/groups, if that's required?)  Are there any error messages in the system log?

Comment: What is the operating system of the machine hosting your repository?  Are you accessing it via the web server?  svn+ssh?

Comment: @Michael
svn is a development tool.  I would consider this a programming question.

Comment: we've tried svn+ssh, and just svn. we're mostly using svn clients like tortoisesvn and versions, but we even tried committing from the server (ssh).

we're running on ubuntu hardy (theres no /etc/groups)

Comment: @Dima - just seems to be more server management related than actual programming.  If it was about how to use SVN best practice for virtual development teams, then I probably wouldn't have said anything about it.

Comment: @Michael - ok, it's a gray area.  But the poster is new, and in need help. :)

Comment: What happens when someone else tries committing? Is there an error message? "doesn't work" doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to focus on things that changed...

svn+ssh requires that you are logged into the repository system and that auth-access = write (in svnserve.conf), at least that's how I've seen it set up.  Is it possible that there were sessions logged into the repository initially, and they are no longer there?

There's a great tutorial on setup:

"Setup Guide for Linux Subversion Server, using SSH client access
(using the svn+ssh protocol with svnserve -t)

Gunther Strube (gbs@users.sourceforge.net, March 2004)"

but you probably already knew that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to delete the local svn authentication cache on each machine accessing the svn server to force each user to authenticate again. The authentication cache is in the user's home directory:
Linux: /home//.subversion
Windows: c:\Documents and Settings\.subverison

Most svn client tools have a debug option - please turn this on and review the output.
I have seen clients that do not handle NTLM authentication very well. The svn server should always offer BASIC authentication on top of NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this. In the end I ended up removing all the users and groups, then recreating them all.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is on a linux box, and you are using svn+ssh, I think setting permissions on the repository can solve your problem.  Ideally, you would want to create a group for all users who need access to the repository and make the repository writable to that group.  If you can't create a group, then you'll have to make it world writable.

Alternatively, you can set up Apache web server to access your repository through the web.  It will work with tortoissvn as well.

Comment: i made it world writeable just to see if it would work, and it's not giving me any luck :/

Comment: Make sure that you are using svn+ssh so that the authentication is done by ssh not by svnserve...  Don't know what else to tell you...

Answer (score 0):

Is a firewall active on the other computers? deactivate it and try again. If it then works, define a proper exception. Maybe then also consider re-enabling the firewall on your machine :-)